# Add Filter to Loop and Filter by month

Tags: silverstripe

Can I add a Filter to a date that filter the month?

I know I can use the filter <% loop $Courses.Filter('DateTo', '12-05-2017') %>, but this is a filter for a specific day. What I would like to do is filter by month i.e. <% loop $Courses.Filter('DateTo.Month', 'February') %>?

Is this possible?

Wesley

Answer (score 1):

For more advance filtering I usually create a function on the model that handles the filtering

```php
/**
 * Courses that take place in given month.
 * 
 * @param   int         $month
 * @return  DataList
 */
public function CoursesByMonth($month)
{
    $year   = date('Y');
    $day    = date('d');
    $endDay = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);

    return $this->Courses()->filter(
        [
            'DateTo:GreaterThan' => $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' 00:00:00',
            'DateTo:LessThan' => $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $endDay . ' 23:59:59',
        ]
    );
}
```

And then you can use it in your template like this

```
<% loop $CoursesByMonth(2) %>
```

I haven't actually tested the function itself, so it's quite possible it doesn't work, but hopefully this gives you an idea of how you can achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help Janne Klouman. I will try this tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I don't get this working. I think it has something to do with my current setup. Let me give you a bit of background on this.

So I have 3 php files located in mysite/code (files below). These files allow you to create a course with different course dates. These courses should be grouped by month and displayed on the homepage (HomePage.ss), but somehow I cannot get this done. So currently I have added some filters to the html, that works partially. So the months are displayed, but the courses are not grouped per month but are grouped by their coursename. At the bottom of this question you will see my workaround.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**1. Courses.php**

```
    <?php
    class Course extends DataObject {
        private static $db = array(
            'DateTo' => 'Date',
            'DateFrom' => 'Date',
        );
        private static $has_one = array(
            'Project' => 'Project'
        );

    }
```

---

**2. Project.php**

```
<?php
class Project extends Page {
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Courses' => 'Course'
    );


private static $db = array(
        'courses_Check' => 'Boolean(1)',
        'courses_Title' => 'Text',
        'courses_Description' => 'HTMLText',
        'courses_TargetAudience' => 'Text',
        'courses_Goal' => 'Text',
        'courses_Length' => 'Int',
        'courses_Costs' => 'Currency',
        'courses_Content' => 'HTMLText',
        'courses_Learnings' => 'HTMLText',
        'courses_Accreditation' => 'HTMLText',
        'courses_Location' => 'HTMLText',
        'courses_AdditionalInfo' => 'HTMLText',     

    );

 public function getCMSFields() {
        // Get the fields from the parent implementation
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('courses_Title','Cursustitel'),'Content');        
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('courses_Description','Cursus beschrijving'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('courses_TargetAudience','Doelgroep'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('courses_Goal','Doel'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new NumericField('courses_Length','Cursusduur aantal dagen'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new CurrencyField('courses_Costs','Kosten van de cursus'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('courses_Content','Inhoud Cursus'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('courses_Learnings','Leerdoelen'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('courses_Accreditation','Accreditatie'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('courses_Location','Cursuslocatie'),'Content');
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('courses_AdditionalInfo','Meer informatie'),'Content');

        // Create a default configuration for the new GridField, allowing record editing
        $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
        // Set the names and data for our gridfield columns
        $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
            'DateTo' => 'Datum van',
            'DateFrom' => 'Datum tot',
            'Project.Title'=> 'Cursusnaam' // Retrieve from a has-one relationship
        ));    
        // Create a gridfield to hold the course relationship    
        $studentsField = new GridField(
            'Cursus Data', // Field name
            'Cursus', // Field title
            $this->Courses(), // List of all related students
            $config
        );        
        // Create a tab named "Courses" and add our field to it
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Cursus data', $studentsField);

        // Remove Content Field
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","Content");
        $fields->removeFieldFromTab("Root.Main","Metadata");

        return $fields;

    }
```

**3. ProjectHolder.php**

```
<?php
class ProjectHolder extends Page {
    private static $allowed_children = array(
        'Project'
    );
}
class ProjectHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {
}
```

**4. My Workaround**

```
      <div class="half">
        <% loop $Projects %>
        <% loop $Courses.Limit(1) %>
        <div class="tab">
          <% if DateTo.Month == "January" %>
          <input id="tab-one" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-one">January</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "February" %>
          <input id="tab-two" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-two">February</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "March" %>
          <input id="tab-three" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-three">March</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "April" %>
          <input id="tab-four" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-four">April</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "May" %>
          <input id="tab-five" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-five">May</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "June" %>
          <input id="tab-six" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-six">June</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "July" %>
          <input id="tab-seven" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-seven">July</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "August" %>
          <input id="tab-eight" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-eight">August</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "September" %>
          <input id="tab-nine" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-nine">September</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "October" %>
          <input id="tab-ten" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-ten">October</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "November" %>
          <input id="tab-eleven" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-eleven">November</label>
          <% else_if DateTo.Month == "December" %>
          <input id="tab-twelve" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
          <label for="tab-twelve">December</label>
          <% end_if %>
          <% end_loop %>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <ul style="line-height:1.8em; margin:10px 0;">
              <% loop $Courses.Sort(DateTo, ASC)  %>
              <li><a href="$URLSegment.Up">$DateTo.DayOfMonth $DateTo.Month $DateTo.ShortMonth - $DateFrom.DayOfMonth $DateFrom.ShortMonth: $Project.Title</a></li>
              <% end_loop %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <% end_loop %>
      </div>
```

Comment: add these to the question not as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

There's too much business logic in the template - you need to simplify.
I don't really understand from the code above, where the $Projects loop is coming from, but my approach would be something like below, moving as much logic as possible on the PHP side. So add this below to the Project class:

```
public function CoursesByMonth() {
  $months = array();

  foreach ($this->Courses() as $course) {
    $month = $course->DateTo->Month();

    if (!in_array($month, months)) {
      $months[] = $month
    }
  }

  // at this point you have all the distinct months, but the array it's not sorted by month, so let's sort it

  $months_sorted = array();

  foreach($months as $month) {
    $m = date_parse($month);
    $months_sorted[$m['month']] = $month;
  }
  ksort($months_sorted);

  // at this point you have a simple PHP array, with all the distinct months from all the courses, in the proper order
  // but this is useless in Silverstripe templates - so we need to do some other stuff here

  $result = new ArrayList();
  foreach ($months_sorted as $month) {
    $courses_for_current_month = $this->Courses()->filter('DateTo.Month' => $month);
    $result->push(new ArrayData(
      'Month'   =>  $month,
      'Courses' =>  $courses_for_current_month;
    ));
  }

  return $result;
}
```

...and then have something like this in the template:

```
<div class="half">
  <% loop $Projects %>
    <% loop $CoursesByMonth %>
    <div class="tab">
      <input id="tab-{$Pos(1)}" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
      <label for="tab-{$Pos(1)}">$Month</label>
    <% end_loop %>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <ul style="line-height:1.8em; margin:10px 0;">
        <% loop $CoursesByMonth.Courses.Sort('DateTo', 'ASC')  %>
        <li><a href="$URLSegment.Up">$DateTo.DayOfMonth $DateTo.Month $DateTo.ShortMonth - $DateFrom.DayOfMonth $DateFrom.ShortMonth: $Project.Title</a></li>
        <% end_loop %>
      </ul>
    </div> <!--/ .tab-content -->
  </div> <!--/ .tab -->
  <% end_loop %>
</div> <!--/ .half -->
```

I didn't tested all this, but from what I understand this is the code I could come up with. **Even if it's not working, it gives you some ideas I'm pretty sure.**